# I'm getting an error indicating that the file path has a space in the name when installing Anaconda on Windows 10

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

When installing Anaconda3 2018.12 (64-bit) on Windows 10, I'm getting an error indicating that the file path has a space in the name ('Program Files' directory on my C:\ drive), and that some Conda packages may have problems with this if I continue.

Does anyone know specifically which packages may have a problem?  I'm using Python primarily for data science (SciPy/NumPy, Pandas, etc.).

See link for a screenshot of the warning.

[image: Anaconda Installation Warning]

Comment: It is strange this is the case because if you were to install Anaconda using the Visual Studio installer it installs just fine.  I realized after I submitted this comment that the Visual Studio might be putting Anaconda in a directory without space.

Comment: Anyways....Anaconda developers are not even clear on the reasons. [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3947) and [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/716).  They say it will work but "other supported stuff that Anaconda supports" might have problems.

Comment: @onhamae Just my two cents but I would take the hint. Not with Anaconda particularly (so I couldn't say which packages for that environment exhibit the issue) but I have certainly encountered "cross-platform" Python packages that throw unresolvable errors over "spaces". Even "vanilla" Python installs itself outside "Program Files" by default on Windows, in a directory without spaces.

Comment: Thank you both.  I did take the advice of the warning (against my desire to maintain organization on my hard drive), but was simply curious if anyone had specifics on the reason.  I can't afford the potential problem at the moment.

Comment: @alofgran, do you remember what you did? I am facing the same warning right now. Did you change the location?

Comment: @B.Anshuman - I simply complied with the warning. I still haven’t found a solid solution, but also haven’t revisited the issue since posting my question.

Answer (score 2):

what i did is: Run the installer as administrator (Right-click on installer to select run as administrator).in order to get...

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

this form to install the program helped me

Comment: Hi @Ray.  Thanks for the contribution, but I was looking to find out if anyone knew the specific Conda packages to which the error above was referring.  I was, fortunately, able to finish the installation though.

Comment: Hi @onhamae you're welcome and how good you could do it

Comment: This worked perfectly, indeed. Just to add: after choosing run as administrator, just leave "Install for: All users" selected. This solves the 1 space problem.

Comment: In case you are unsure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXrqJe9fB3Q

Answer (score 0):

Check that there is no space in the naming of your destination folder. Check here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejKaXo2pqwQ

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that occurred because if you see the location of your destination folder in the image you posted in your question, it has a space in the name of "Program Files". So maybe, if you were to use command prompt or shell and for example - change directory to "Program Files", it may cause some issues in not identifying the exact directory you want it to.

And maybe, this is because it wants you to have the application stored in some directory which can be easily accessed using command prompt and which has no spaces in its name.

Actually, I was doing the same thing but in some folder named as "Setups and Applications". It created an error message saying that 2 spaces are not allowed, and so I have to do the installation in some other folder that had no space in its location. It worked fine when I selected a folder that had no space in its location.